# Not able to control-drag from a Table View to a detail view in a storyboard

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, xcode4.5

I'm trying to learn how to use storyboards but am having a problem with control-dragging from my Table View to the detail view; it basically, doens't `auto-connect` like I have something configure wrong.

Here's what it kinda looks like:
[image]

Should I even be able to do this?

Here's my code for cell creation:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"MyCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell==nil){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text=self.tasks[indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

Here's the code in my view controller (although this wouldn't seem relevant):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"taskSegue" sender:self.tasks[indexPath.row]];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"taskSegue"])
    [destination setValue:sender forKeyPath:@"task"];
  else
    destination = [segue.destinationViewController topViewController];

  [destination setValue:self forKeyPath:@"delegate"];
}
```

thx fo

Comment: i can't see the cell in your tableview, in the screen shot.

Comment: Yeah, the directions I'm trying to follow don't seem to think I need a cell there. I'm not sure if that's correct or not

Comment: if you are looking for a detail view while selecting a cell from the tableview, you should drag from the cell in the tableview controller and connect to your detail viewController. I am sorry if you know this already.

Comment: Thx Arun - you are correct; by just dragging out a Table View Cell, I was able to complete. you can make answer and I'll accept if you want.

Comment: glad that i could help you. Happy coding

Comment: i have written the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a detail view while selecting a cell from the tableview, you should conrol drag from the cell in the tableview controller and connect to your detail viewController.